# Cannot launch Elixir desktop app when MIX_ENV=test

Tags: elixir, desktop, phoenix-live-view

### Background

I have Phoenix umbrella application. When inside said application, I can run it without issues if `MIX_ENV=prod`. However, if I do `mix test` while `MIX_ENV=dev`, I get an error.

### Problem

The error I have is as follows:

```
18:39:42.101 [error] ** wx object server {:local, WebInterface} terminating
** Last message in was {:"$gen_cast", {:show, &WebInterface.Endpoint.url/0}}
** When Server state == %Desktop.Window{
  module: nil,
  taskbar: nil,
  frame: {:wx_ref, 35, :wxFrame, []},
  notifications: %{},
  webview: {:wx_ref, 49, :wxWebView, []},
  home_url: &WebInterface.Endpoint.url/0,
  last_url: nil,
  title: "Market Manager",
  rebuild: 0,
  rebuild_timer: {:interval, #Reference<0.2679771817.2635857922.255366>}
}
** Reason for termination ==
** {:badarg,
 [
   {:erlang, :binary_to_existing_atom,
    ["Elixir.WebInterface.Endpoint.HTTP", :utf8],
    [error_info: %{module: :erl_erts_errors}]},
   {:elixir_aliases, :safe_concat, 1,
    [file: ~c"src/elixir_aliases.erl", line: 139]},
   {WebInterface.Endpoint, :url, 0,
    [file: ~c"lib/web_interface/endpoint.ex", line: 4]},
   {Desktop.Window, :prepare_url, 1,
    [file: ~c"lib/desktop/window.ex", line: 666]},
   {Desktop.Window, :handle_cast, 2,
    [file: ~c"lib/desktop/window.ex", line: 604]},
   {:wx_object, :handle_msg, 5, [file: ~c"wx_object.erl", line: 493]},
   {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: ~c"proc_lib.erl", line: 241]}
 ]}
```

Reading this, I understand the problem comes from my `application.ex`, namely:

```
@impl true
  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      Telemetry,
      {Phoenix.PubSub, name: PubSub},
      Endpoint,
      Manager,
      %{
        id: Desktop.Window,
        start:
          {Desktop.Window, :start_link,
           [
             [
               app: :web_interface,
               id: WebInterface,
               title: "Market Manager",
               size: WindowUtils.calculate_window_size(0.6, 0.8),
               menubar: MenuBar,
               icon: "static/images/resized_logo_5_32x32.png",
               url: &WebInterface.Endpoint.url/0    # This line seems to be a problem
             ]
           ]},
        restart: :transient,
        shutdown: 5_000
      }
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: WebInterface.Supervisor]

    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
```

After reading more on the subject I changed my `config/test.exs` to this:

```
import Config

config :web_interface, WebInterface.Endpoint,
  http: [ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, port: 4002],
  secret_key_base: "some_key",
  server: true,
  check_origin: false
```

But this still does not fix the issue.

In contrast, this is my `config/prod.exs`:

```
config :web_interface, WebInterface.Endpoint,
  http: [ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, port: 80],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json",
  secret_key_base: "some_key",
  check_origin: false,
  server: true
```

But the issue still occurs.

### Questions

- Why am I having this issue?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: In your umbrella's `mix.exs`, what does the dependency to :web_interface look like? The error message about a failure to convert "WebInterface.Endpoint.HTTP" into an existing atom implies to me that that module is not loaded when `MIX_ENV=test`, so perhaps you have `only: [:dev, :prod]` or a constrained :targets that applies for that dependency?

Comment: Another possibility is that you reference a module called `WebInterface.Endpoint.HTTP` only in the test context, either through a config option targeting MIX_ENV=test or some other sort of conditional evaluation (e.g. `if Application.compile_env(:some_app, :some_prop, :some_default) do something()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Turns out that in a previous launch of the application, wxWidgets (the process) had exited in a bad state. Perhaps it crashed or something else happened, but what matters here is that trying to restart it was impossible.

I had to restart my machine to start everything in a new clean state.
I also deleted the `_build` folder to be sure.

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That error message is indicating a problem with [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org). I'd guess that Desktop.Window is using wxWidgets.  One way to insure that wxWidgets is working correctly is to try to start Erlang observer.  Do this within iex:

```
:observer.start()
```

If observer starts correctly then wxWidgets is fine and the problem lies elsewhere.  If it doesn't start then you'll need to figure out what's wrong with wxWidgets.

I'm not sure why Desktop would behave differently from test vs. production.